# mongodb watch cursor with match statement doesn't work

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using mongodb 3.6.9
I have the following statement in my nodejs backend express app.
after passing the match statement to the watch function, I do not get any change updates at all. what am I doing wrong?

```
    const projectCollection = db.collection('projects');

    watchProjects = projectCollection.watch(
        [{ $match: { _id: new ObjectID(projectId) }}],
        { fullDocument: 'updateLookup' }
    );

    watchProjects.on('change', change => {
        console.log(change);
        socket.emit("update", change.fullDocument);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

ok after 2 hours of reading documents the following works, posting here for reference for other:

```
[{ $match: { 'documentKey._id': new ObjectID(projectId) }}],
```